# Expandable and collapsible feature is working when clicking the checkbox

Tags: html, responsive-design, datatables, html-table

I have created a table using `jquery` `datatable`. I am also using the responsive feature of the `datatable` for making it responsive. The code is working fine but the issue I am facing is that the the first column of the table is having a check-box and when we resize the table width to a lesser width collapsible option will appear like as shown below

[image]

Now when we click the `checkbox` the collapsible feature is working.

My code is as given below

**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mTvMMtYSsmszV9peaeDA?p=preview)**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive display nowrap" cellspacing="0"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            :
        </tbody>
   </table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="dataTables.responsive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example')
                .DataTable({
                    "responsive": true,

                    "dom": '<"top"lf>t<"bottom"pi><"clear">'
                });
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to prevent collapsible and expandable when we click the `checkbox`

Comment: Couldnt get it working in your example for some reason so i didnt post an answer but this looks promising - create a new column and then use it as the target for the details option https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.details.target

Comment: The reason is that you have placed `collapsible button` and `checkbox` is same `td`. That's why by checking `Checkbox` it is enabling `Collapsible` functionality..

Comment: and `collapsible option` is applicable at whole `first td`, not just at clicking `plus sign button`.

Comment: @user55 collapsible button is part of datatable responsive plugin also the clicking functionality for the first column, can we override the datatable responsive plugin

Comment: just add one more td at position 0, **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sAZpfAquuQDGGjVn1aaZ?p=preview)** is its working demo.

Comment: did you try z-index ?

Comment: @eronax59 no,,...can you show me an example

Comment: @AlexMan Please refer this about z-index. Z-index is used to make your div/attribute to top or bottom. have a look. By this you can give z-index higher to your (+) sign, and it will be clickable as you want. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: @eronax59 couldn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just replace

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
       "responsive": true,
       "dom": '<"top"lf>t<"bottom"pi><"clear">'
    });
});
```

by

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
       "responsive": true,
       "dom": '<"top"lf>t<"bottom"pi><"clear">'
    });

    $('td').on('click mousedown mouseup', function(e) {
        if (e.target.type === 'checkbox') {
           e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
});
```

this part will stop click propagation if you clicked on a checkbox

```
$('td').on('click mousedown mouseup', function(e) {
    if (e.target.type === 'checkbox') {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PCHdDM7UGD0BLXoDhhD6?p=preview

EDIT:

To remove cell click functionnality and add it only to collapse/expend button, I had to create a new html element and put it in the cell: `'<div class="clickBtn">+</div>'`

Why? Because the old button was a before pseudo:element so it was not actually in the dom. I needed an element in the dom to only allow expend/collapse when this particular element is clicked and not the whole cell.

Then I'm giving this button the css of the old button

```
.clickBtn {
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none; 
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none; 
   -ms-user-select: none; 
   user-select: none;        
   cursor: pointer;
   top: 9px;
   left: 4px;
   height: 14px;
   width: 14px;
   position: absolute;
   color: white;
   border: 2px solid white;
   border-radius: 14px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 3px #444;
   box-sizing: content-box;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
   line-height: 14px;
   background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

and remove the old one:

```
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>td:first-child:before, table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>th:first-child:before {
   display: none;
}
```

Now I need to change the cell click behavior, to only occur if you click on the collapse/expend button.

```
$('td').on('click mousedown mouseup', function(e) {
   if (e.target.className === 'clickBtn showBtn') {
       if (e.target.innerText === '+') {
           e.target.innerText = '-';
           e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
       } else {
           e.target.innerText = '+';
           e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#337ab7';
       }
   } else {
       e.stopPropagation();
   }
});
```

When you click on the cell, if the target of your click is not an element with 'clickBtn' and 'showBtn' class it stops the event propagation. That's why only the clickBtn can expend/collapse now.

this part just recreate the old button color and text changing :

```
if (e.target.innerText === '+') {
    e.target.innerText = '-';
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
} else {
    e.target.innerText = '+';
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#337ab7';
}
```

EDIT 2 :

To remove the blue part, which is text selecting, I had to add this css to the button:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none; 
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none; 
-ms-user-select: none; 
user-select: none;
```

Comment: Can we remove the click functionality from the cell, and apply click functionality only to collapse and expandable button

Comment: the color of the collapsible and expandible buttons are changing to navy blue, also cursor clickable is still there for the cell (but no action)

Comment: just updated my plunker, do you understand what I did, in order to make all this work, or do you need explanations?

Comment: it would be better if you can give me. Also one more issue which I have seen is when I double click the collapsible expansible button I am getting a bluecolor like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8XneW.png)

Comment: Add some explanations and removed the blue color of text selecting, and sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker

Answer (score 6):

just add one more `td` at position 0

**[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sAZpfAquuQDGGjVn1aaZ?p=preview)**  is its working demo

Comment: but the newly added column is not hiding when collapsible button is hidden., can we overide the plugin

Comment: yes you can overide the plugin. you can change its CSS etc. but don't make changes in plugin files. Just excess the classes/IDs used in plugin, add changes in your design file say HTML file.

Comment: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jsYxF2KV5yBnGIGTNVZD?p=preview) - changed css for child `tr`

Comment: i mean how to hide the column if there are no collapsible button, i.e if collapsible comes the new added column should be visible, if not it should be hidden, this will solve our issue

Comment: can we achieve this by using css

Comment: a collapsible (or something like it - firebug it to see exactly) class is added to the table when the table enters responsive mode - using this you should be able to selectively show the column when its in responsive mode. 

side note - adding the extra column at the first position works due to that being the default of the details.target setting, so changing this setting you could add your column wherever you wanted.

Comment: @ChrisHopkins I have given 50 bounty for the question....could you please help me on this

Comment: forked version with CSS to hide/show the column - the padding does go a little wonky but im sure some tinkering should sort this. http://plnkr.co/edit/39xIkDza6tzuu37fhbkY?p=preview

Comment: @ChrisHopkins Thanks for the reply. Can we remove the click functionality from the cell, and apply click functionality only to collapse and expandable button

Comment: not easily as the button itself is a background image on the cell so the cell is the expand button.