# DataTables Responsive Expand / Collapse only when icon is clicked (exclude other content in cell from click event)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I understand that the solution to this is to have the expand / collapse icon in it's own column, however, for the app I am working on I would like the icon to be in the first column along with the cell content, which in this case is a checkbox.

[image: https://snag.gy/mYgpBH.jpg]

With the expand / collapse icon in the first column when the checkbox is checked / unchecked it triggers the expand / collapse of the DataTables row. Is there a way to only trigger the expand / collapse by the icon only (ie excluding all other cell content)?

What I have tried:

- It appears as though the expand / collapse is bound to the cell (td) click event
- The icon is generated by css :before on the cell (td) DOM element
- As such I have attempted to detect the DOM element that has been clicked and if not td [e.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) or [e.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) to stop the expand / collapse but the expand / collapse events still occur

  ```
  // class .wpsc_ticket_row on tr DOM element captures click event to open ticket
  jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.wpsc_ticket_row', function( e ) {

      //  captures clicked DOM element
      var cell = jQuery( e.target );

      // check if clicked DOM element is td
      if ( cell.is( 'td' ) ) { 

          // exclude first column from opening ticket by detecting wpsc_exclude class
          if ( !cell.hasClass( 'wpsc_exclude' ) ) { 

              // get ticket id
              var ticketId = jQuery( this ).data( 'id' ); 

              // open ticket
              addOpenTicket( ticketId, true ); 

          }

      // if clicked DOM element is not td check closest td for wpsc_exclude
      } else if ( !cell.closest( 'td' ).hasClass( 'wpsc_exclude' ) ) { 

          // get ticket id
          var ticketId = jQuery( this ).data( 'id' ); 

          // open ticket
          addOpenTicket( ticketId, true ); 

      } else {

          // if clicked DOM element not td and does not have class wpsc_exclude stop all events
          e.stopPropagation(); // e.stopImmediatePropagation()

      }

  }
  ```

Any suggestions appreciated. TIA

Comment: Why not setting click listener  to desired element instead of `wpsc_ticket_row` ?

Comment: The table contains a list of support tickets. Clicking the row in any cell except the first opens the ticket

Comment: Is'nt you question to set the listener only on the icon not entire the row?

Comment: Listener for Expand / Collapse triggered by icon only, excluding all other elements in the cell. Other cells in the row are irrelevant to the question. Cell contains icon and checkbox. If checkbox clicked expand / collapse occurs which i don't want to occur

Comment: You can not select :before and :after using jquery. You need a hack. I suggest a transparent relative positioned element on upper layer of the icon (beside of checkbox).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Do you want that on checking/unchecking checkbox row expand/collapse functionality should trigger?

Comment: That already happens because the checkbox is contained within the td DOM element. I need the checkbox to not trigger the expand / collapse event

Comment: Then you need to add checkbox in separate `td`. Please have a look at [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585049/expandable-and-collapsible-feature-is-working-when-clicking-the-checkbox)

Comment: As my question states I understand that a separate column is a solution, but i am hoping to find a solution which will allow the icon and checkbox to co-exist in the same td. So far not looking promising....

Comment: Were you able to solve this. I have the same requirement but found no solutions to that.

Comment: No, never resolved sorry

Comment: try look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585049/expandable-and-collapsible-feature-is-working-when-clicking-the-checkbox